# How can I sort a list WITHOUT removing duplicates?

Tags: java, sorting, duplicates

How can I sort a list WITHOUT removing duplicates in Java?

Given a list with duplicates {3, 1, 2, 1, 4 },
it should be sorted so that I get {1, 1, 2, 3, 4 } at the end.
I don't care about the order of the duplicates.
It should work for arbitrary data structures with well-defined comparators.

Java List.sort(comparator) removes duplicates.
There is no extra parameter to preserve duplicates.

Comment: "Java List.sort(comparator) removes duplicates" where does the documentation say this?

Comment: *"Java List.sort(comparator) removes duplicates."*, could you post that code?

Comment: Your question is based on a false premise, as mentioned above

Comment: Thanks. I was confused,

Answer (score 1):

The question is based on a false premise. `List.sort()` does not remove duplicates.

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3, 1, 2, 1, 4));
    numbers.sort(null);
    System.out.println(numbers);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

([Try it on repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/GrowlingGloomyLocatorprogram))

Comment: And I want to add that the [List#sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) implementation is *stable* that means it won't change the order of duplicates.

Comment: he asks about unstable sort and avoids the stable one in the mergesort

Comment: @sc0der Say again? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I guess he asking about the un-stability of the sort algorithm and he doesn't care in duplicate keys

Comment: @sc0der ? *"How can I sort a list WITHOUT removing duplicates in Java? [...] I don't care about the order of the duplicates."* ?

Comment: @akuzminykh yes, "don't care about the stability" so I posted the answer to use `Quicksort` which is the primitives' sort

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Arras.sort(result)` in java, it's based on `Quicksort` and not stable, so convert the List of integer to int array and do the sort

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3, 1, 2, 1, 4));
    int[] result = list.toArray(new int[0]);
    Arrays.sort(result);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```